# Makefile pattern rule limitation

Tags: makefile

Consider the following simplified `Makefile` :

```
target :
    (recipe)

target-mt : (add some flags)
target-mt : target
```

This example works as intended : `make target-mt` add a few flags and proceeds with compiling `target`.

Now, since the `*-mt` pattern happens quite often, with always the same flags, I want to make this effort common. So let's simplify with a [Makefile pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) :

```
target :
    (recipe)

%-mt : (add some flags)

target-mt : target
```

This works as intended, and now all later `*-mt` targets receive the same additional set of flags.
Now, notice that the dependency of `something-mt` is always `something`. So I'm tempted to generalize this relation even more :

```
target :
    (recipe)

%-mt : (add some flags)
%-mt : %
```

This one **doesn't work**.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `target-mt'.  Stop.
```

This seems at odd with general formulation of pattern rules, such as the canonical example :

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I presume there must be a reason for this failure, and I presume it might be related to the fact that the dependency is a pure `%`, not something more defined like `%.c`. But I couldn't find anything related to such a restriction in the documentation (linked above).

Questions are :

1) Is there an explanation for this behavior ?

2) Is there another way to achieve the same objective ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a pattern rule with no recipe.  Or rather, you can, but it doesn't do what you want here: instead it [cancels the pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html).

You could add a dummy recipe, like this:

```
%-mt: % ; @:
```

(`:` is a shell no-op operator).

Or you could just not use this and go back to the way it was.  It's a little hard to understand the full context from this limited example.

Comment: OK, so what makes the pattern rule `%.o : %.c` work is the fact that it's followed by an actual recipe, not just a dependency ?

Comment: Correct.  A pattern rule without a recipe cancels the pattern rule.

Comment: Thanks !
And btw, as suggested, adding a fake recipe, or a trivial one like `echo something` does work !